# ¿Es posible obtener el formato día - mes - año con base R?

Tags: r, funciones, date, datetime

Estoy intentando crear un vector de fechas para, digamos, el período del 1 de enero de 2018 al 31 de octubre de 2019 empleando base R. Lo que se me ocurre es primero crear ese vector utilizando las funciones `seq` y `as.Date` de la siguiente forma:

```
fecha <- data.frame(fecha=seq(from = as.Date("2018-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d"), 
    to = as.Date("2019-10-31", format="%Y-%m-%d"), by = 1))
```

Lo que nos regresa lo siguiente:

```
str(fecha)
## $ fecha: Date, format: "2018-01-01" "2018-01-02"
```

Ahora bien, comúnmente nosotros empleamos el formato día - mes - año, y, para tener ese formato, empleamos la función `format`.

```
fecha[,"fecha"] <- format(fecha[,"fecha"], "%d-%m-%Y")
str(fecha)
'data.frame':   669 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ fecha: chr  "01-01-2018" "02-01-2018" "03-01-2018" "04-01-2018" ...
```

El formato es el deseado pero las fechas ahora son de tipo caracter. Si intento coercionar empleando otra vez `as.Date` vuelvo prácticamente al principio:

```
fecha[,"fecha"] <- as.Date(fecha[,"fecha"], format="%d-%m-%Y")
str(fecha)
'data.frame':   669 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ fecha: Date, format: "2018-01-01" "2018-01-02" ...
```

¿Alguna solución a este problema? Me interesa tener una en base R y agradecería cualquier solución adicional (entiendo que las librerías `zoo` y `lubridate` permiten trabajar con fechas aunque honestamente desconozco sus funciones principales)

Gracias de antemano por cualquier orientación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer punto que quiero señalar, es:

> una cosa es el dato y otra muy distinta es la representación del
>   mismo.

En el caso de un `Date`, el dato en sí, es un número que representa la cantidad de días desde el 1/1/1970.

```
as.numeric(as.Date('1970-01-01'))
[1] 0
```

El dato podríamos decir que es agnóstico del formato. La representación al usuario es la que eventualmente podría tener un determinado formato. Un dato `Date` se representa mediante la función `print.Date()` que no establece ningún formato en especial, por lo que se usa el formato por defecto de `format.POSIXlt()` que es justamente el formato menos ambiguo, el ISO, es decir `yyyy-mm-dd`. Si quisieras modificar esto, la buena práctica, es usar `format` con el formato deseado, la conversión a una cadena es la única forma de poder mostrar este dato, mantén el dato con la clase original y solo usa el `format` para mostrarlo al usuario. Sino la única forma, sería modificando la función base `print.Date()` para que use un formato específico, esto, de todas, formas es algo eventualmente peligroso, digo modificar una rutina base, tiene sus riesgos:

```
print.Date <- function (x, max = NULL, ...) {
  if (is.null(max)) 
    max <- getOption("max.print", 9999L)
  if (max < length(x)) {
    print(format(x[seq_len(max)]), max = max + 1, ...)
    cat(" [ reached 'max' / getOption(\"max.print\") -- omitted", 
        length(x) - max, "entries ]\n")
  }
  else if (length(x)) 
    print(format(x,format="%d-%m-%Y"), max = max, ...)
  else cat(class(x)[1L], "of length 0\n")
  invisible(x)
}
```

Con el código anterior, efectivamente, cada vez que muestres una fecha, la verás con el nuevo formato:

```
as.Date('2019-12-17')
[1] "17-12-2019"
```

Comment: Cuando te refieres a riesgos, ¿hablas de alguna inestabilidad del sistema o efectos no deseados? Gracias por tu respuesta, siempre terminas dándome cátedra. Saludos.

Comment: Hola Alejandro, tal vez este caso no sea peligroso, pero lo cierto es que una función base, o en realidad cualquiera que no sea de nuestra autoría, tiene un "contrato" con el resto de las funciones que la usan, modificar este "contrato" puede eventualmente traerte un problema que seguramente no va a ser fácil de encontrar cuando ocurra. Imagina que existiera una función X que extrae los primeros 4 caracteres de un `print(fecha)` para saber el año, si es un caso muy poco probable, pero la idea básicamente es esa.

Comment: Entendido. Muchísimas gracias :)